# I accidentally deleted the users from the C drive and put it on the D drive. How can I fix this so my system works again?

Tags: windows, users, recovery

I was low in space in C drive, I copied users from C drive and pasted it to D drive and deleted the users in C drive.

I realized I have made big mistake by doing this. How can I  undo the damage and restore the C drive to normal?

Comment: Try making a symlink to the `c:\users\username` but point those to the `D:\users\username` restart and then see if that works. I've never done it but it could work but depends on if you changed the registry too I suppose. Otherwise, try just coping one of the `C:\users\username` folder back from the "D" drive, reboot, and then see if it lets you login as that user again and works correctly.

Comment: Is reboot necessary?? I tried copying it from the D drive to C drive it didn't work :(

Comment: You cannot. I am shocked you didn’t get an enormous amount of errors deleting a profile directory while it was in use

Comment: I'm not certain but give it a try to see just in case it is that simple. I don't see any harm in trying it

Comment: I hope you have a backup of your documents, otherwise tomorrow is going to be a mess for you.

Comment: I don't have any backup and all my important files were saved there, including a 100+ hrs Android development project if I don't my submit my project tomorrow I don't know how I will face the world

Comment: @HimanshuMohapatra - I assume your unable to log into Windows? You really don’t specify what your problem is other than you realize you shouldn’t have deleted your user profile. Additionally, you have specified how you were able to do that, while you were logged into the user. It sounds like you deleted your only copy of vital files, without a backup, there isn’t a solution to your problem. Feel free to edit your question to provide that necessary details

Comment: @Ramhound sir after I deleted users from C file the desktop icons disappeared and background wallpaper disappeared and changed to black with only recycle bin present as a desktop icon I then copied my users and pasted as it is to c drive users and deleted that was present in d drive,  then rebooted the laptop, then the wallpaper appears with some other apps like chrome Adobe reader and mozzila sir I am still unable to get photos and downloads that were present in the c drive what to do?

Comment: @HimanshuMohapatra - Create a new user, this will create a new profile directory, you broke your existing user profile. It sounds like you have access to your personal files, are able to finish your project, and wait to properly deal with it by performing a full clean install of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy the files back. Keep in mind that the users folder is a special folder. If the permissions are not set correctly, you will not be able to boot from those profiles, resulting in creating a TEMP folder inside C:\Users.

Because the special rights on this folder, creating a symlink will not work. You have to copy the C:\Users folder back first and hope that the rights have copied back with it. If not, your own user must be the owner of your folder and have full control on the folder too.

C:\Users, System and Administrators both have full control on the file, Users is read only. SYSTEM user is owner of the folder C:\Users.

After setting all permissions as it should be, reboot and pray.

Once this works again by setting the folder rights as above, you can then move folders from inside your user to another place and use `mklink /d <name> <target>` from an elevated command prompt to move folders. Although this will work with appdata, documents, desktop, etc... it will not work on your user folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

By doing that, you also made hidden changes in other places, such as the Registry. The best choice is to restore the disk from the last disk image. An image is easy to make using free tools such as [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/).

If you do **not** have an existing disk image, your best, and perhaps only, option might be to [reinstall Windows from ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), keeping files. Then create each user with the same name, password and privileges as before and finally copy files for each from D:\Users. This is slow, tedious and prone to errors. Even when done perfectly, some applications registered *per user* would have to be reinstalled.

**However, the documents and projects in `D:\Users\...` are still accessible;** you cannot use that as an excuse for late submission ;-) Just make a bootable USB device (thumb drive) to access the files; there's no need to install anything. Quickest might be a [Ubuntu Live USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview), and there are numerous alternatives, such as [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/), [Hiren's Boot CD](https://www.hiren.info/) and [others](https://alternativeto.net/software/ultimate-boot-cd/). BTW, the nice thing about Ubuntu Live is that it already has LibreOffice on it so you can make last-minute edits to docs -- but save them some other place than the C: or D: drives.

Comment: This is not entirely correct nor the best answer.